# If date is next week/next month/ next year

Tags: php, date

I was wondering if it is possible to use PHP to figure out when a specific date it.

For example:

```
// Next week
$date->setDate(2014, 4, 3);

if($date->format('Y-m-d') == NEXT_WEEK){
// Do something
}elseif($date->format('Y-m-d') == NEXT_MONTH){
// DO something else
}elseif($date->format('Y-m-d') == NEXT_YEAR){
// Do something else
}
```

I understand my code won't work, but I am looking for something that would achieve something similar to that?

Comment: Define "next week", "next month" and "next year". What has to match for them to be true?

Comment: The date will be pulled from the database. I want the script to read the date and say "that date is next week", "that date is next month" or "that date is next year"

Comment: That didn't answer my question. What is "next week"? Same week number? Same day of the next week?

Comment: E.g., if today is Wednesday, when is "next week"? 4 days' time (Sunday), 5 days' time (Monday) or 7 days' time (Wednesday)? For "next month" is it change in month or in 28/29/30/31 or 32(!!!) days? For "next year" is it change in year or in 365/366/365.25 days?

Answer (score 3):

Easy Going with `strtotime()`:

```
<?
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setDate(2014, 5, 2);


if($date->format('U') >= strtotime("next year")){
  echo "next year";
}elseif($date->format('U') >= strtotime("next month")){
  echo "next month";
}elseif($date->format('U') >= strtotime("next week")){
  echo "next week";
}

?>
```

keep in mind, that just using `>=` requires you to check FIRST for the year, then for month and then for week, cause `strtotime("next year") > strtotime("next month") > strtotime("next week")`.

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved with [DateTime](http://php.net/datetime) objects using diff to see the time in between, something like this should do the trick:

```
// The date we want to check
$checkDate = new DateTime('2014-04-03', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
// We need to compare it against today + a specific interval,
// so create a seperate DateTime object for today
$today = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));

// Check the difference between the dates
$diff = $today->diff($checkDate);

if ($diff->y == 0 && $diff->m == 0 && $diff->d == 7) {
    // Date lies a week in the future
} elseif ($diff->y == 0 && $diff->m == 1 && $diff->d == 0) {
    // Date lies a month in the future
} elseif ($diff->y == 1 && $diff->m == 0 && $diff->d == 0) {
    // Date lies a year in the future
}
```

Comment: This is a very narrow interpretation of the question and I'm not sure this is want they are looking for. But I like your approach as I had something similar in mind.

Comment: @JohnConde I know, this is just a nudge in the one of the possible directions to achieve what he's after.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the various definitions of "next week", "next month" and "next year", there are several ways to approach this that use the PHP date format parameter, explained in the PHP manual [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). There is also a need to check the upper boundary to ensure that the date does not go past next week/month/year.

```
  <?php
    $checkdate = strtotime('+8 days');
    $datenow = time();

    $diff = $checkdate - $datenow;

    echo "Today: ".date("Y-m-d", $datenow)."<br/>";
    echo "Target: ".date("Y-m-d", $checkdate)."<br/>";

    $days = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24)/ (60*60*24));
    $months = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24) / (30*60*60*24));
    $years = floor($diff / (365*60*60*24));

    $daytoday = date ('N', $datenow);
    $dayofmonthtoday = date ('j', $datenow);
    $dayofmonthtarget = date ('j', $checkdate);
    $monthtoday = date ('n', $datenow);
    $monthtarget = date ('n', $checkdate);
    $yeartoday = date ('Y', $datenow);
    $yeartarget = date ('Y', $checkdate);
    // $dayofyeartoday = date('z', $datenow);
    // $dayofyeartarget = date('z', $checkdate);



    if ($days >= 8-$daytoday && $days <= 14-$daytoday) {
         echo "Next week (Monday onwards)<br/>";
    }

    if ($days >= 7-$daytoday && $days <= 13-$daytoday) {
         echo "Next week (Sunday onwards)<br/>";
    }

    if ($days >= 7 && $days <= 13) {
         echo "Next week (7-13 days)<br/>";
    }

    if ($monthtarget == $monthtoday + 1) {
         echo "Next month (Change in month)<br/>";
    }

    if ($monthtarget == $monthtoday + 1 && $dayofmonthtarget >= $dayofmonthtoday) {
         echo "Next month (Change in month but at least same day in the month and before end of that month)<br/>";
    }

    if ($yeartarget == $yeartoday + 1) {
         echo "Next year (Change in year)<br/>";
    }

    if ($yeartarget == $yeartoday + 1 && $years == 1) {
         echo "Next year (Change in year but at least same day and month in the year and before end of that year)<br/>";
    }

?>
```